# Understanding the Usage and Purpose of InteractionType in @azure/msal-browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure, azure-ad-msal, msal-react

I'm currently working with the `@azure/msal-browser` library and I came across the term `InteractionType`.

Which is mentioned as an Enum in the documentation [link to documentation (archived)](https://web.archive.org/web/20230421110321/https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/enums/_azure_msal_browser.interactiontype.html).

However, I couldn't find detailed information on how to use it and its purpose.

Could someone please provide a more comprehensive explanation of what `InteractionType` is used for within the context of `@azure/msal-browser`?

It would be great to have some code examples or practical scenarios where this enum comes into play.

I appreciate any insights or references to relevant resources that can help me understand this concept better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interaction type defines how a user of the application protected by Azure AD will authenticate themselves.

If the interaction type is `Redirect`, the user will be redirected to Azure AD for authentication. Here they will essentially leave your application and once they are successfully authenticated, they will be redirected back to your application.

If the interaction type is `Popup`, user will be presented with a popup where there can sign in (if needed). Here the user never leaves your application and the authentication interaction happens in a popup.

If the interaction type is `Silent`, MSAL will try to authenticate user based on existing token stored somewhere in cache used by MSAL.

Comment: thanks for your answer, can you please also mention the use of interactionType.None

Comment: I searched through the code on Github and it seems InteractionType.None is not even used in the code. You may want to ask this question here - https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/60c4aafa567ffee9d418d51913833fab214d366b